# How to copy all cells from DataGrid without selecting?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a DataGrid below `XAML` code:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding GetCar}" CanUserAddRows="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id, StringFormat={}{0:D8}}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Brand" Binding="{Binding Brand}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Model" Binding="{Binding Model}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Year" Binding="{Binding Year}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Color" Binding="{Binding Color}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

C# code:

```
public partial class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}

private IEnumerable<Car> car;

public IEnumerable<Car> GetCar
{
    get
    {
        car.Add(new Car {
            Id = 1,
            Brand = "Honda",
            Model = "Fit",
            BodyType = "Sedan",
            Color = "White",
            Condition = "Good",
            EngineCapacity = "1.5",
            Helm = "Right",
            Transmission = "Automatic",
            Year = "2004"
        });
        return car;
    }
}
```

In fact, the data is taken from the Database and there are a lot of them. They are sorted.

There is one more `Button` which when pressed all cells from `DataGrid` should be copied to the clipboard.

Comment: forgive me what should I do? and I did not understand you

Comment: Why does `GetCar` call `Add` every time you call it? That is **super unexpected**. "How many cars do you have on sale?" 5 "What about now?" 6 "And now?" 7 "And now?" 8. Why does your code do that?

Comment: I'm new to this, I did not know this ))

Comment: Just have a `DataGrid` and a `Button` and I need to copy the data to the clipboard from DataGrid when I press the Buttons

Comment: And I do not sell cars

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy `carList` to clipboard and get it later you can do something like:

```
 var carList = new List<Car>()
 for(int i= 0;i<= dataGridView1.Rows-1;i++)
     {
        carList.Add(new Car
                      {
                        Id = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value,
                        Brand = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value,
                        Model = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value,
                        Year = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value,
                        Color = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value
                });
} 
System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetDataObject(carList);
var carListFromCB = System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(carList.GetType());
```

In WPF to get Row content :

```
public IEnumerable<DataGridRow> GetDataGridRows(DataGrid grid)
 {
    var itemsSource = grid.ItemsSource as IEnumerable;
    if (null == itemsSource) yield return null;
    foreach (var item in itemsSource)
    {
      var row = grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as DataGridRow;
                if (null != row) yield return row;
    }
 }
```

and calling `GetDataGridRows` like:

```
 var rows = GetDataGridRows(datagrid1);

 foreach (DataGridRow r in rows)
 {
   Car carItem = r.Item as Car;
   carList.Add(carItem);
 }
```

Comment: sorry, I need to copy from Datagrid

Comment: See the edit, I supposed your grid Id is `dataGridView1`

Comment: dataGridView Window Form? I have DataGrid not DataGridView